# Rails: Hide Facebook permission page while login through facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Hi I am using Rails 2.3.5 to develop an application, where i am supposed to have an option for user to login through facebook. So currently i am using FB Graph API to do this using "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_APPLICATION_URL/"

Whenever user clicks on the Fb Connect button, a popup will open with above url which takes him to facebook login page. user inputs his username and password and click login. Next FB permission page will be opened.

I don't need any user information from Facebook, so is there any way i can avoid displaying / hide permission page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that providing the facility to log into your app as a user will give you the ability to access some of their information. While I trust that your app won't use this information like you say - the folks at Facebook are far less trusting ;-)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, hope this info helps me and likes of me.